# disable the warnings in VS code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVDnO.png)

When I click **Disable(Workspace)** the error is:

> Cannot disable extension 'ESLint'. Extension 'Node.js Extension Pack' depends on this.

In what other way can react-native errors be eliminated???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `.eslintignore` file in your root directory and add the path of the folder you wish to ignore from linting.

Reference: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories

Answer (score 2):

The suggested way to solve the issue is to resolve all the linter issues as they can help you to overcome some scaling issues and make your code consistent.
Workaround for the problem is you can create a file .eslintignore in the root directory of your project and add the file path for which you want to disable the linter.

To disable the Eslint. You can follow the steps.

1. Navigate to the folder where you defined package.json (Project root directory).
2. Create a new file with the name `.eslintignore`
3. Edit the `.eslintignore` to add the files where you do not want the linter. Example, you have an src directory where all the react code is present, you want to diable linters for whole src directory. Add the following line in .eslintignore.

`src/*`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you can disable it all but this worked for me for the time being add this // eslint-disable-next-line before the line it warned about