# VSCode: how to disable warnings about deprecated Node.js features

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using VSCode for a Javascript project that runs in a browser JS engine; it will never and can't run in Node.js. But Intellisense quite dramatically warns about features in my code that are deprecated in Node.js. Is there a way to tell it, that this is not a node but a browser project to get only relevant warnings?

[Strikethrough in code and warning in Intellisense popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vKBJ.png)

Comment: Are you using some type of linter like eslint? and please share a picture of your warnings if you can

Answer (score 0):

if you use eslint as linter. You can do it in the .eslintignore file in your root directory.

take a look here: [disable the warnings in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907471/disable-the-warnings-in-vs-code)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I'm not using eslint (in this project) and the warning is not in the "problems" pane but in the intellisense popup and by striking through the code in the editor.