# Override deprecated styling in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have a JavaScript project that utilizes `window.external` and it has started showing the external property as being deprecated.  The project used it because originally native code was exposed in the Internet Explorer browser this way.  When the company migrated to using WebView2, they continued to expose via `window.external` to maintain passivity.

[image: window.external showing as deprecated]

How can I flag to VSCode that `window.external` is not deprecated for this project so that it doesn't appear with a strikethrough?

EDIT: I believe this was autoclosed indicating that it is a duplicate of [disable the warnings in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907471/disable-the-warnings-in-vs-code) which is incorrect.  Doing some more digging, the deprecation comes from TypeScript's lib.dom.d.ts (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts).  The only way I've found to overcome this is to define the `compilerOptions.lib` property of a jsconfig.json file however that is an all or nothing change.  Meaning that I lose all type definitions for the DOM.  I need another way to override the deprecation.

Comment: You probably meant "highlighting" not "styling"?